# OpenCV-Python: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I have the following Python code which throws the error in the title:

```
# calculate number of all ROI pixels inside defined(hsv -) color range 
pts2 = cv2.findNonZero(mask_final)
non_zero_pixel = int(len(pts2))
```

Similarly here as well:

```
# calculate number of all ROI pixels inside defined(bgr -) color range "black"
pts = cv2.findNonZero(mask_black)
black_pixel = int(len(pts))
```

I translated this piece of code from its C++ version which did work without an error:

```
// Calculate number of all ROI pixels inside defined (hsv-)color range           
vector<Point> pts2;
findNonZero(mask_final, pts2);
double non_zero_pixel = static_cast<int>(pts2.size());
```

I don't know why the Python version makes a problem whereas C++ version does not.

Any thoughts?

**EDIT: Exception details:**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-119-f76eaba94311> in <module>()
     28 
     29 if __name__ == "__main__":
---> 30     main() # pass the list of arguments from the command line

<ipython-input-119-f76eaba94311> in main()
     16 
     17         # detect screws
---> 18         detectScrews(img)
     19 
     20         for j in range(len(screw_radiuses)):

<ipython-input-118-4c225e9bc794> in detectScrews(img)
     80             # calculate number of all ROI pixels inside defined(bgr -) color range "black"
     81             pts = cv2.findNonZero(mask_black)
---> 82             black_pixel = int(len(pts))
     83 
     84             # if number of black pixel is lower than threshold

TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

Comment: Have you checked the docs to see what condition causes `cv2.findNonZero(mask_black)` to return None?

Comment: Why does not the C++ version do the same? I am running it on the same image. Python one fails, C++ one passes. It's weird.

Comment: Because the functions may have different behavior in regards to what they return and when. Again, the docs will likely hold the answer here.

Comment: I tried to answer you question in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that there are no non-zero elements in `mask_final`.

This shows the same error:

```
print(len(cv2.findNonZero(np.zeros([3,3], np.uint8))))
```

---

> Why does not the C++ version do the same? I am running it on the same image. Python one fails, C++ one passes. It's weird

Python returns the type `None`, which is the typical Python way of specifying there is nothing. You could for example then write (very Pythonic):

```
if cv2.findNonZero(np.zeros([3,3], np.uint8)) is None:
    print('I didnt find any zeros')
```

Languages like `C++` don't have a distinct type that has the same meaning. It does have a `Null`, but it's essentially just a `0`. Which means that if the function returns a `Null`, it could be mistaken for the element at index `0`. The `None` in Python is its own, and doesn't mean `0` at all.

Comment: I used the conditional statement to let the program continue only if the returning value is not none, and it worked. Thanks.